# Merging text files in ascending order of their contents

Tags: python, sorting, merge, text-files

I was wondering if you guys had any input on how to efficiently go about doing this, I currently have a working implementation using Python's collections class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how much memory you have available (and the size of the files of course).

If you have enough memory available than I'd personally just take the easy way and create a list of all items and do a `sort()` on them.

Something like this:

```
# Read all except the first (header) lines
lines = file('1.txt').readlines()[1:]
lines += file('2.txt').readlines()[1:]

lines.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split()[0]))

print ''.join(lines)
```

Alternative for the lambda:

```
def key(x):
    return int(x.split()[0])
```

Comment: Chose this because it's the most Pythonic answer, and the one a variation of which I wound up using. Thank you go to the two of you though, great answers.

Comment: @Louis93: the lambda functions are pretty much the same as normal functions but without a name. This is just a function that takes a parameter `x` and returns `int(x.split()[0])`.

Comment: @Louis93: I've added the normal version of the lambda for clarity :)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> files = ('1.txt','2.txt')
>>> lines = (map(int,line.split()) for f in files
             for line in islice(open(f),1,None))
>>> sorted(lines,key=itemgetter(0))
[[1, 23112, 3], [2, 32344, 1], [12, 19872, 0], [123, 12243, 1], [221, 39873, 5], [234, 34555, -4]]
```